# Download external html content client side, send to django server, send processed data back to client

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

this is what I want to do. I am a newbie at javascript and django. Please let me know how I can go about doing this:

1. Client clicks button on web page, javascript downloads html content from external website.
2. Javascript sends html content (likely a web page) to django server.
3. Django server executes a specific function on the html content, and returns

   1. a JSON serialized piece of data and
   2. a modified version of the downloaded html content.
4. Javascript displays 1 and 2 client side.

How do I go about doing this? I suspect I need JQuery AJAX for 1), but I can't seem to get it to work with external html. For 2)-4) I am completely lost. Please help, forgive my newbie-ness.

UPDATE: I don't want to get the html content from the server for a reason. If I do that with a lot of users the site I get content from will block the server from further downloads.

Comment: You want http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/   This will allow django to download the external webpage directly. You could then use BeautifulSoup to modify the html. No Javascript required

Comment: No that is not what I asked for. I need to make requests for html content from the client side for a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not make that all bit shorter:

1) Visitor clicks on button on webpage and your webpage sends address of html page to your django server.

2) Django executes the web request using urrlib2 (for example) and downloads the webpage by itself.

3) Django executes that function on content and returns the a) and b)

4) javascript displays a and b.

So what you need:

1) jQuery ajax to send the url to your server.

2) look up some basic examples for django urllib2 about hot to make web requests. Its pretty simple and easy too.

3) Get http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ for parsing html you have downloaded with urllib2. Modifying and parsing html documents is super easy with it. If you look up examples and try them out, you will see it yourself.

4) And then just return the html and/or json using django's own Http methods.

Alan

Comment: Thanks, but there is actually a good reason why I am not doing the url requests from the server. If all requests originate from the server then the sites I am getting html content from will block the server's ip address. So in this case all html content must be downloaded from the client side. Otherwise your solution would be perfect. Any thoughts on how to answer my original question?

Comment: Well you cant do javascript requests from browser that are not directed towards server that is not the origin of content : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. And i highly doubt that your IP would be blocked based on http requests.

Comment: Some googling pointed out this link though : http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/. I still would recommend doing it on server side though as html parsing is much faster with python than with javascript. Also if you are worried about beeing ip-banned/blocked, then you can save the html into database to reduce the amount of requests you do.

Comment: Odif I will try this out, although so far I haven't had success with these methods.

Comment: Well thats why i suggest you use urllib2 instead. I HIGHLY doubt anyone wound ban a ip for http requests.

Comment: Odif, I am really new at javascript and I couldn't figure out how to use the YQL thing. Would you mind posting a sample html page that pulls the html content from www.google.com into a string?

Comment: Also, the requests I plan to make are on a specific api that is monitored and run with a use policy that blocks users if traffic from an ip address increases past a certain point. An alternative solution would be to make the server requests look like they are coming from a different ip address, but I don't know where to begin with that.

Comment: About jquery and sample request - thats exactly what this page does:http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/. Download jquery, download jquery.xdomainajax.js from https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/. Put them into your html document. And then execute them using your code. That same github page also contains another downloadable example - use that as your starting point :)